# Project Settings disappeared in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, settings.settings

Today I was add a new SETTING into the VS2013 Project´s Properties page (at Design Mode) and I see that ALL settings had disapeared!  My Settings page is clean (the settings called through "my.settings.xxxx").

But, when I run the application in DEBUG or RELEASE mode the system functions normally - and I reference a lot of "my.settings" in there!

How can I solve it?  I´m affraid of SYNCHRONIZE and clean the DEBUG/RELEASE files too!

Help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

1- Go to Project Solution Explorer.
2- Click in the symbol to SHOW ALL FILES
3- At the My Project folder, simply delete the Settings file.
4- Go to the Project´s Properties page and select Settings.
5- In the middle of the screen will appear a message to Import Settings.
6- Done! VS had imported all the project settings (from where, I don´t know exactly).

Comment: The ONLY problem is about all settings had been imported as STRING! So, I had to mannually change the settings were BOOLEAN, INTEGER, COLOR and so forth...  But it´s better than manually input entirely all of them.

Comment: Good for you.I tried the same but Properties.Settings still were missing. Luckily enough, I just started the project and it contained just a form so I saved it as template, removed the project and added a new one. That project got corrupted somehow, I guess.